# Install SSRS SP mode after SP2016 is setup not working

Tags: 2016, reporting-services, sql-server-2016, report-builder

We are using SP2016 on-premise with SQL 2016 enterprise edition. After everything is setup we realize we also require SQL Reporting service enable on the farm. Hence, on our application server we installed "Reporting Service - SharePoint mode" and "Reporting service Add-in" with **SQL Server 2016 installation media**.

After that, we create SQL reporting service application and the service is **Started** in Application server. Finally, in CA -> manage web application -> select our existing web application -> Service connections -> we changed "default" group to "custom" group connection and check "SQL Reporting service"

[image]

It looks like I have completed the setup but I am failed to connect my builder to the SSRS. Also I found several things weird.

1. No **Reporting Service Configuration Manager** is installed on app server therefore I cannot start or configure the service.
2. Cannot find report content type on any library.
3. I create a new site collection with BI center template. But the content type doesn't show up properly. [image]
4. In service console (services.msc) I cannot find SQL Server Reporting Service on App server. I can only find it on SQL server.

Could you advice what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to follow the [directions outlined for SSRS integrated mode installation and configuration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/install-the-first-report-server-in-sharepoint-mode?view=sql-server-2016). From the sounds of it, you're more familiar with an SSRS native mode installation. Since SSRS integrated doesn't use the same configuration path, your best bet is to read the guide on how to install and configure it properly.

I'd also recommend against it. SSRS integrated mode no longer exists after SSRS 2016. And SharePoint Server 2019 does not support SSRS integrated mode, either. Your upgrade path for this configuration will be to move to an SSRS native mode/Power BI report server/Power BI online/other reporting solution.

Comment: my purpose is to build some Reports using SQL report builder 2016. Then upload to SharePoint and allow my users browse the reports. Could native mode do the same?

Comment: Yes, using SSRS Native you can either do this via the native interface or you can expose reports on an SSRS native instance via the [Report Viewer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-sharepoint/deploy-report-viewer-web-part?view=sql-server-2017). I would strongly consider using SSRS native and if you want to present the reports via SharePoint, use the viewer.

Comment: Hi Trevor, I successfully create a report using native ssrs. I can load the report via http://sqlserver/reportserver/sp-reports/spreport with my account DOMAIN\MARK. However when I try to add it in Report viewer it only throw me generic error. Checking ULS in web front end get `SPSecurityContext: Could not retrieve a valid windows identity for username 'DOMAIN\MARK' with UPN 'MARK@domain.com'. UPN is required when Kerberos constrained delegation is used. Exception: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException: Access is denied. `

Comment: Do you have KCD configured?

Comment: It is first time I aware this term KCD. If it is not enabled by default I think we don't have. 
Our sharepoint is installed on sharepoint.com and my account is on domain.com. The report's datasource is using a sharepoint.com domain.

Comment: At the moment I use Page Viewer webpart to show my report. It seems Power BI also use same approach.